# Is there a good way for testing firebase storage security rules?

Tags: firebase, testing, firebase-storage, firebase-security

For Firestore i can use the emulator to write tests, but for storage there is no emulator unfortunately.

I have tried the simulator in the firebase console but i don't want to type all my tests into there every time i change my rules.

I know that i could write tests that test against the deployed rules on a project, but that has several disadvantages.

Is there something similar to the Firestore emulator for storage rules?

Comment: There is not, currently.  There might be some day.  Please file a feature request to indicate interest.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: @DougStevenson Damn that was quick! thanks will do!

Comment: @DougStevenson so i did some digging and found this: [Firebase Rules Api](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#search/firebaserules/firebaserules/v1/). That is the api that the simulator in the console uses. I tried writing a little script to check if i can use it but i am not able to authenticate ("Error: The caller does not have permission"). I generated an api key in the gcloud console for that api but it does not work.

This is what i am trying: https://gist.github.com/dergoegge/1e9cbf980148ef3febecaf0eeeb0e1fa

Comment: Sounds like you have a new question to post here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no firebase supported way of testing storage security rules, but I found this the [Firebase Rules API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?hl=en_US#search/firebaserules/firebaserules/v1/) which has unit testing functionality for both firestore and storage rules. The simulator in the firebase console uses this API as well.

I filed a feature request for this but for now I wrote a small npm package using this API for unit testing:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-security-testing

https://github.com/dergoegge/firebase-security-testing

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth pointing out that you can test also the storage security rules in the Firebase console now. (It just saved me a lot of confusion I got from a syntax change...)

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Storage for Firebase emulator was [released in July 2021](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2021/07/the-cloud-storage-for-firebase-emulator.html), and it's now included in the [Build unit tests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests) document.

Here's some example test code using the [v9 JavaScript API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js):

```js
import { assertFails, initializeTestEnvironment } from '@firebase/rules-unit-testing';
import { getBytes, ref } from 'firebase/storage';

describe('Storage', () => {
  let testEnv;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
      projectId: 'demo-project',
      storage: { rules: fs.readFileSync('storage.rules', 'utf8') },
    });
  }

  afterAll(async () => {
    await testEnv.cleanup();
  });

  it('disallows access for unauthorized users', async () => {
    const storage = testEnv.unauthenticatedContext().storage();
    await assertFails(getBytes(ref(storage, 'file.json')));
  });
});
```

However, it seems like uploading into the emulator may be broken at the moment (late December 2021): https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3780